# Combine 2 arrays in a query parameter

Tags: wp-query, array

I'm trying to exclude upsells using `post__not_in` but I already have a value and do not know how to combine the two.

I tried this:

```
'post__not_in' => get_upsell_ids(), [get_the_ID()]
```

But it is not working.

My code:

```
function eligo_custom_related_products_by_label() {
    
    if (is_product() && has_term('records', 'product_cat')) {

        global $post;

        if ( ! $post ) {
            return;
        }

        $related_by_same_label = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'pa_label', ['fields' => 'slugs']);

        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post__not_in' => [get_the_ID()],
            'tax_query' => [
                'relation' => 'AND',
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ],
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'pa_label',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $related_by_same_label,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>

            <section class="related products">
                <div class="related__inner">
                    <?php
                    $attribute_names = ['pa_label'];
                    foreach ($attribute_names as $attribute_name) {
                        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($attribute_name);
                        if ($taxonomy && !is_wp_error($taxonomy)) {
                            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $attribute_name);
                            $terms_array = [];
                            if (!empty($terms)) {
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    $archive_link = get_term_link($term->slug, $attribute_name);
                                    $full_line = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                                    array_push($terms_array, $full_line);
                                }
                                echo '<h3 class="section__title">' . esc_html__('More from', 'eligo') . ': ' . implode(', ', $terms_array) . '</h3>';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    woocommerce_product_loop_start(); 

                    while ($loop->have_posts()):
                        $loop->the_post();
                        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                    endwhile;
                    
                    ?>
                </div>
            </section>
            <?php

        } 

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'eligo_custom_related_products_by_label', 20);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've adjusted the question to avoid it being closed as offtopic, 3rd party plugin support is not in scope here, but this problem appears to be basic PHP rather than WordPress, namely that you haven't discovered how to merge 2 arrays/lists together, or recognised that this is what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because this is not how you merge two arrays:

```php
'post__not_in' => get_upsell_ids(), [get_the_ID()]
```

Instead you need to take those 2 arrays and combine them using `array_merge`, a standard PHP function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Note that `__not_in` type parameters have a very high performance cost and do not scale, this query will be very slow and require caching.